# Role based user permission handling in a application

Tags: c#, database, winforms, security, mvp

In a windows forms payroll application employing MVP pattern (for a small scale client) I'm planing user permission handling as follows.(Roll based)

**NOTE** : System could be simultaneously used by few users (maximum 3) and the database is at the server side.

*User Tables in the database.*

```
USER (user_id[pk], name, access_level, status)

PERMISSION (permission_id[pk], permission_detail)

USER_PERMISSION (user_id[pk][fk], permission_id[pk][fk])
```

I would maintain user list in `USER` table and permission list in `PERMISSION` table (permission details are the accessible module names). Intermediate table `USER_PERMISSION`  would map the users with the permissions. `UESR` and `PERMISSION` tables have `1:M` relationships with `USER_PERMISSION` table.

When an user login to the system, first the system will validate the user and if its valid then the home screen will be shown and the logged user's `ID` will be hold in a global variable (accessible to all presenter classes) . When the user try to access a specific module, the system will read that global variable to find the current user's `ID` and then it will look in the `USER_PERMISSION` table whether there is an entry relevant to that user id and the module name in which the user is trying to login. If there is and entry, then the user will be given the access to that particular module.

When user log off the variable holding the current user id will be cleared.

1. In this approach is it okay to hold the current user's `ID` in application memory? or should be written to a local file?
2. Modifications to the data in the tables should be tracked and in this purpose should I maintain a separate column on each table (ones should be monitored) to hold the `ID` of the user who is modifying the record?

**EDIT**:

1. Can we use `SQL-SERVER` user rolls/ logins in this purpose? and can this user action login stuff be handed over to `SQL-SERVER`?

When controlling `Read/Write` permissions in `Forms`, the respective `Presenter` handle the logic and set the properties in the `View` (properties like `IsModifyAllowed{get;set;}`, `IsDeleteAllowed{get;set;}` etc.) according to the current users permissions. So that the View could handle the rest of the things by `enabling / disabling` controllers in the `View`.

1. In this approach should the every Model have a matching property like in the view(in this case `IsModifyAllowed{get; set;}` etc. )?
2. What is the most widely used approach in this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you have described in your first part of the question is pretty common, although it's not actually Role based, it's permission based.

It's not a perfect solution, although no security mechanism really is.  But it's pretty simple and works.

To answer your questions.

- There shouldn't be a problem with holding the id in memory, so long as we're not talking about government level security here, and there is no real concern about people breaking into the machines and trying to gain access, in which case there are probably much bigger fish to fry.  Storing it in a file may actually make it less secure, and you would eventually have to read it into memory at some point anyways.
- Tracking changes can be simple or complex, depending on how you want to do it.  You can add a last modified field, but this will only track the most recent change.  To be safe, you need an audit table that tracks all changes and keeps historical versions of the data.  It's probably a good idea to do this audit table with a trigger so that your application code doesn't have to remember to do it.
- Yes, you can use SQL server logins and roles, but this probably won't make things easier or less complex.  With your model, you're controlling access to modules via a permissions table.  Using SQL Server Roles, you would have to control access via data, and react to exceptions thrown for not being able to access things, or query the database for roles and have to do things in tables anyways.  If you have Windows domain, you might want to consider using Active Directory instead.
- I don't completely follow what you're saying about Views and Model properties, because you haven't adequately explained your models.
- There is no "most widely used approach", everyone does it differently.  Although there are a number of things people tend to do.  Microsoft offers a number of approaches, for instance they have what's known as the Composite UI Application Block and Authorization Manager.  You can read about an interesting impelementation here: [Granular Role Based Security](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa480723.aspx).  Jesse Liberty offers another take [Here](https://www.simple-talk.com/dotnet/windows-forms/controls-based-security-in-a-windows-forms-application/)

In short, this is something you will have to work out yourself, because there are literally thousands of ways people have done this (if not millions).  Do some research, and try to come up with what works best in your situation.